# How to find matching columns in multiple tables in a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, join, multiple-columns

How to find matching columns in multiple tables in a SQL Server database?

I have a SQL Server database with over 30 tables, is there a way to filter and/or produce a list of the common columns amongst the tables rather than going through each manually?

Maybe some code?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: microsoft sql server management studio

Comment: [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/information_schema_views/)

Comment: [See also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this with multiple tables

Comment: It's going to be something similar to [this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1274391/Comparing-two-tables-to-find-matching-column-names-or-missing-columns-and-datatype#bm1274996).

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comments, you want to use system table [sys.columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to achieve your goal.

This query lists all column names that are present more than once in the database, along with the number of occurences :

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) 
FROM sys.columns 
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

You can join the results with [sys.tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to recover the corresponding tables, like :

```
SELECT
    C.name AS ColumnName,
    T.name AS TableName
FROM
    (SELECT name FROM sys.columns GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) A
    JOIN sys.columns C on C.name = A.name
    JOIN sys.tables T ON T.object_id = C.object_id
ORDER BY
    C.name,
    T.name
```

Comment: The second code is returning nothing, just the columns 'ColumnName' and 'TableName'

Comment: @actuario99 : maybe you just don’t have duplicated column names in your database... Does the first query return something ?

Comment: yes the first query returns the names of the columns and the # of times it appears

Comment: @actuario99 : ooh right, there was a glitch in my query, I just fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something easy like this:

```
SELECT [Unique name #] = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY c.name)
    , [Column] = c.name 
    , [Column type] = t.name
    , [Column max length] = c.max_length
    , [Column precision] = c.precision
    , [Table schema] = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(c.object_id)
    , [Table name] = OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id)
FROM sys.columns as c
INNER JOIN sys.systypes as t ON t.type = c.system_type_id
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(c.object_id,'IsTable') = 1
    and  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(c.object_id) != 'sys'
ORDER BY c.name;
```

Comment: how would I modify this for the views instead of the tables?

Comment: In "OBJECTPROPERTY" use "IsView", but that is not the best way. You can join it to "sys.views" or "sys.objects" instead of using "OBJECTPROPERTY"

Answer (score 0):

With this query you have all the columns with same name in different tables of your DB:

```
select object_name(c.id) + '.' + c.name + ' ' 
        + t.name
        + case when t.xtype = t.xusertype then '' else '[' + tr.name end 
        + case 
            when tr.name in ('bit', 'tinyint', 'smallint', 'int', 'bigint', 
                            'float', 'money', 'smallmoney', 'real', 'date', 'time', 
                            'datetime', 'datetime2', 'smalldatetime', 'timestamp')
            then ''
            else 
                case when isNull(c.prec,0)=0 then ''
                else '(' 
                    + case when c.prec = - 1 then 'MAX' else cast(c.prec as varchar) end
                    + case when c.scale is null then '' else ',' + cast(c.scale as varchar) end
                    + ')'
                end
          end
        + case when t.xtype = t.xusertype then '' else ']' end
        + case when t.collationId <> c.collationId
             then ' collate ' + c.collation collate Latin1_General_BIN else '' end
        + case c.isnullable when 0 then ' not null' else '' end
        + case c.colstat
            when 1 then ' identity(' + Cast(Ident_seed(o.name) as varchar)
                      + ',' + cast(Ident_incr(o.name) as varchar) + ')'
            else ''
          end
        + case when cm.text is null then ''
          else ' default '
            + case when patindex('% as %', cm.text) > 0
              then rtrim(substring(cm.text, patindex('% as %', cm.text) + 4, len(cm.text)))
              else substring(cm.text, 2, len(cm.text) - 2)
              end
          end
        as Columns
from syscolumns c
join systypes t on (t.xusertype = c.xusertype)
left join systypes tr
    on (tr.xtype = t.xtype and tr.xusertype = t.xtype)
join sysobjects o
    on (o.id = c.id)
left join syscomments cm
    on (cm.id = c.cdefault)
where c.name in (
        select cl.name
        from syscolumns cl
        join sysobjects ob on (cl.id = ob.id and ob.xtype = 'U')
        group by cl.name
        having count(*) > 1
        )
order by c.name
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLS where TABLE_NAME = 'table1name'
intersect
select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLS where TABLE_NAME = 'table2name';
intersect
...
...
..
...
select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLS where TABLE_NAME = 'table30name';
```

sql server equivalent:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
intersect
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table2'
intersect
.....
....
...
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table30';
```

Comment: Would I have to change the 'COLUMN_NAME' part?                                                         SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '[dbo].[vClaim]'
intersect
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '[dbo].[vClaimTransaction]'

Comment: no column_name will be like that change table1 table2 ... names

Comment: It just returns 'COLUMN_NAME' as an empty column name

Comment: these two tables have several common columns

Comment: hmm still getting errors .'The multi-part identifier "hcdc-dwSQL01.ODS.dbo.vClaim" could not be bound.'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185467/discussion-between-nikhil-sugandh-and-actuario99).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the query which will provide you the list of all tables where your "Column" is present.

```
SELECT c.name AS ColName, t.name AS TableName FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id WHERE c.name LIKE '%ColumnName%';
```

And based on that you can continue you task you want to perform.

Thumbs up if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

select name as 'Column_Name' from syscolumns s1 where id = object_id('table1') and
       exists(select 1 from syscolumns s2 where s2.name = s1.name and s2.id = object_id('table2'))

it will return the matched columns